# Populate more than one drop down using the same mysql query

Tags: php, jquery

I have form with a number of drop boxes which have the numbers 1-5 in them.  I can use this code to populate a drop down but was wondering if I can somehow only make the call to the db once but populate all the drop downs that use the same numbers?

```
    <?php                         

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM riskNumDrop";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
     echo "query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
    echo '<select  class="assess" name="precontcons"   style="width:4em">' ;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){echo '<option value='.   $row['riskNumDrop'] .'>'.$row['riskNumDrop'].'</option>';}
    ?> </select>
```

So Ideally, I generate the output once and reuse it multiple times. Im guessing an array (which $result already is) but how do I populate a drop down from it?  TIA

Comment: You're executing the query twice in your code. If you don't have any very special reason for doing that, you definitely shouldn't do that.

Comment: Im not sure I follow @DawidFerenczy when  you say the code is executing twice.  Do you mean in the above code or in the script if Im calling for the same information more than once?  I understand if you mean in the scropt but If you mean in the above code can you explain how?  I can see the execution in the second line where it is put in the array $result but am at a loss to see it being executed again elsewhere.  Happy to be proved wrong though as I am all for getting my code cleaner.

Comment: You don't see you're calling `$conn->query($sql)` twice? It's even on two consecutive lines. The first time you execute the query and assign the return value to the variable `$result`, the second time you execute the same query and just test the return value in a condition without assigning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving as a string would save you the processing of having to loop through the same data generating the same output multiple times. If this is what you want, you could do the following.

Replace:

```
echo '<select  class="assess" name="precontcons"   style="width:4em">' ;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){echo '<option value='.   $row['riskNumDrop'] .'>'.$row['riskNumDrop'].'</option>';}
?> </select>
```

with:

```
$drop = '<select  class="assess" name="precontcons"   style="width:4em">' ;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  drop .= '<option value='.   $row['riskNumDrop'].'>'.$row['riskNumDrop'].'</option>';
}
$drop .= '</select>';
```

Then you can `echo $drop` several times if you want.

---

If for whatever reason you want different select attributes, you could just save the options list and print the select around that, like this:

```
$dropOptions = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $dropOptions .= '<option value='.   $row['riskNumDrop'].'>'.$row['riskNumDrop'].'</option>';
}
```

Then just `echo '<select class="foo" name="bar">'.$dropOptions.'</select'>`

Comment: This would just allow him to output two *identical* dropdowns, but not two dropdowns using just the same data.

Comment: I don't know what he desires nor I'm trying to guess it, but he should just understand the difference.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think he wants the identical dropdowns since I don't know what would be the purpose of having such form (with the same named / identified form elements). But as I wrote that's up to him, I'm just trying to help him to understand it.

Comment: I'd assume he wants identical, but just accounted for if not.

Comment: Im liking this smemy however the first line with the select in it has unique names which need to correspond to columns in the db.As it stands now every time I echo $drop it gives me the same select name which wont work for me.  I tried moving the $drop= to the start of the while loop but I cant make it work.

Comment: @AdrianFischer, check below the horizontal rule in my post

Comment: Thanks @smerny.  Thats exactly what I was after.  Cant believe I was wracking my brain over how to do it.  I am thinking I could make $dropOptions into a session variable and use it on several pages.  Thanks  a million.

Comment: @AdrianFischer, you could, but that would be kind of odd if it's not specific to the user. Also, the query would get ran for every user. If this data never changes, is the same for every user, and is used on several pages... it might make more sense just to hard code it into a global variable. If all those conditions are true except for the "never changes" you might look into caching it on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data into an array, and then print the data by enumerating the array.

```
$risks = array();

// Load values into array.
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($row['riskNumDrop']);
}


// Drop down #1
echo '<select>';
foreach ($risks as $risk) {
    echo '<option value='. $risk .'>'. $risk .'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

// Drop down #2
echo '<select>';
foreach ($risks as $risk) {
    echo '<option value='. $risk .'>'. $risk .'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply get the results into an array using the [`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) method. It returns all rows from the result set into an associative or numeric array. The you can do whatever you want with such array:

```
$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM riskNumDrop');
if (!$result) {
   echo "query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
   exit; // fetch_* functions cannot be called on error (sice $result is false)
}

// get all rows from the result
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// output first dropdown...
echo '<select name="dropdown_1">';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // options for the first dropdown (same as you did before)
}
echo '</select>';

// output second dropdown...
echo '<select name="dropdown_2">';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // options for the second dropdown
}
echo '</select>';
```